# How can I inject a version to a bundled JS file using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a WordPress site with which I'm using Webpack to bundle my CSS / JS files.

I can append a version to my enqueued bundled files using WordPress's `wp_enqueue_script` function. For example, I can append a version to those files using PHP, like `theme.bundled.js?ver=12345`.

However, there are some Code Splitting files from Webpack that don't get this version as they are Code Split via Webpack. What's the best way to inject a version into the file's name?

### Here's my Webpack Config:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        theme: __dirname + "/src/js/theme-scripts/App.js",
        product: __dirname + "/src/js/product-scripts/App.js",
        shop: __dirname + "/src/js/shop-scripts/App.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "js/[name].bundled.js", // These are all imported using WordPress wp_enqueue_script, and have a version appended to them.
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/"),
    },

    //devtool: "eval-source-map",
    watch: true,
    devtool: false,
    stats: "minimal",
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "css/[name].css" })],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [{ loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader }, { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } }, { loader: "sass-loader" }],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

### Here's an example of a code splitting feature:

```
let lightbox;

function triggerLightbox(e) {
    if (!e.target.closest(".dimension__image")) return;

    if (typeof lightbox == "undefined") {
        import(/*webpackChunkName: "Lightbox" */ "./Dimension-Lightbox")
            .then((result) =>
                setTimeout(() => {
                    lightbox = result.displayLightbox(e);
                }, 60)
            )
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    } else {
        lightbox.displayLightbox(e);
    }
}
```

This will output `Lightbox.bundled.js`. I'm looking for a solution to output `Lightbox.bundled.js?ver=12345`.

Comment: you can use the Webpack's `output.chunkFilename` option and `contenthash`. The `contenthash` will generate a hash based on the content of the file, so whenever the file content changes, the hash will change as well. Something like: `output: {//...other setting,
chunkFilename: "js/[name].bundled.[contenthash].js",
}`

Comment: Let me know if this helps post which I'll make an answer to it

Comment: Thanks for this, but is there a way to achieve this with Code Splitting?, I've amended my question.